# Mysql: Confused about query joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

**Warehouse**

- WarehouseID
- WCity

**Shipment**

- OrderID
- WarehouseID
- ShipDate

I am looking to list the `orderID` for orders that were shipped from all warehouses that the company has in New York.

The query I tried

```
select orderID
from shipment
join shipment on warehouse.warehouseID = shipment.warehouseID
where warehouse.Wcity = "new york";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a self `join` instead of joining another table. Try the following:

```
select s.`OrderID`
from `Shipment` s
join `Warehouse` w on w.`WarehouseID` = s.`WarehouseID`
where w.`WCity` = 'new york';
```

Comment: The column city is not in the Shipment table... It's in the warehouse table like I said. It's the city of where the warehouse is located

Comment: It's okay I appreciate the help. Your query gave me an error: Unknown column 'w.city' in 'where clause'

Comment: @archer: well, is your column in the table `Warehouse` called exactly `City`? It seems like it is not.

Comment: Oh wow my professor named the column differently in two places. Its called Wcity. My mistake

Comment: Thanks a ton man that's it. Last time I don't view the actual database and just take the professors word